# Parsing arithmetic expression with variable using menhir

Tags: parsing, ocaml, arithmetic-expressions, menhir

parser.mly:

```
%{
  let env=Hashtbl.create 10
%}
%token <int> INT
%token SUB
%token EOL
%token EQUAL
%token NAME
%left SUB EQUAL

%start main             /* the entry point */
%type<int> main
%%
 main:
  expr EOL                { $1 }
;

expr:
   INT                     { $1} 
  | expr SUB expr           { $1 - $3}
  | var EQUAL expr {Hashtbl.add env $1 $3;0}
  | var {Hashtbl.find env $1}
;

var:NAME {$1}
```

(the 12's line is: `%type<int> main`)

using:

```
wangkai@wangkai-ThinkPad-X1:~/src/ocaml/lexonlysub$ ./calc
a=1
0
b=2
0
b
2
a
2
^C
```

I don't know why after define b=2,then a is 2 too,it should be 1.Why got 2?

and this:

```
wangkai@wangkai-ThinkPad-X1:~/src/ocaml/lexonlysub$ ./calc
a=1
0
b=2
0
a-b
0
```

lexer.mll:

```
{
open Parser
exception Eof
}
rule token = parse
  [' ' '\t']     { token lexbuf }     (* skip blanks *)
| ['\n' ]        { EOL }
 | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm { INT(int_of_string lxm) } 
| '-'            { SUB }
|['a'-'z']+ {NAME}
|'=' {EQUAL}
| eof            { raise Eof }
```

Thanks!

calc.ml

```ml
open Syntax

let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    while true do
      let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
      print_int result;
      print_newline ();
      flush stdout
    done
  with Lexer.Eof -> exit 0
```

makefile:

```
calc:lexer.cmo parser.cmo syntax.cmo calc.cmo 
    ocamlc -o calc lexer.cmo parser.cmo syntax.cmo calc.cmo

lexer.cmo:lexer.mll
    ocamllex lexer.mll
    
parser.cmo:parser.mly
    menhir parser.mly

syntax.cmo:syntax.ml
    ocamlc -c syntax.ml

calc.cmo:calc.ml
    ocamlc -c lexer.ml
    ocamlc -c parser.mli
    ocamlc -c parser.ml
    ocamlc -c calc.ml
```

Comment: I don't understand how your code even compiles, When I try to run it through `ocamlyacc`, I get "File "bla.mly", line 25: $1 refers to terminal `NAME', which has no argument".

Comment: I have add the calc.ml and makefile.I am sorry,I use menhir for the syntax,I forget...

Comment: You don't seem to be returning the actual name at `var:NAME {$1}` or the lexical rule that underlies it: so you aren't distinguishing between different names. I don't know menhir but in C this is done via `var:NAME {$$ = $1}` in the .y file and `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* { yylval.text = strdup(yytext); return NAME;}` in the .l file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a payload to `NAME`. Otherwise, it won't register the string that was lexed; instead, the value it gives you is just `()`, so every time you access your hash table you access the same element.

You need to add the `string` type to `NAME`:

```
%token<string> NAME
```

to have a `string` payload. You also need to actually remember that payload in the lexer:

```
| ['a'-'z']+ as name { NAME(name) }
```

(these two snippets should replace their equivalent in your code)

You can ensure that you have the appropriate type by adding some annotations:

```
%{
  let env : (string, int) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 10
%}
```

(if you add this annotation to your current version, it should fail; but it won't with the appropriate payload added to `NAME`).

Comment: Thanks!and now this prog can run many tests but this one can't:a=1-4 after this prog tell me a's value is 1 but not -3.I check the prog but can't find reason.The expr in "var EQUAL expr" rule can only match the rule "expr SUB expr",so it seems should give me -3

Comment: @wangkai this is a problem of priority, it's relatively easy to fix but I invite you to ask a new question (to avoid answering multiple questions in one place).